# drupal 8 node content with apostrophes or semicolons fails to save

Tags: php, drupal-8

I'm having a strange issue with a Drupal 8 site. If the body field for a node contains a semicolon or an apostrophe, the node will not save. Instead clicking Save redirects me to the home page of the site. If I remove the apostrophe or semicolon, the node saves fine.

The server is running Drupal 8.2.6, PHP 5.6.30, MySQL 5.5.54.

Has anyone experienced this before? I've not found any similar issues on d.o. so I'm wondering if it could be a PHP ini setting.

Here's some additional info:

Looking in the browser console, when content successfully saves, the response has a status of 303 See Other and the Location response header is set to something like the content overview page.

When the save fails, the response has a status of 302 and the Location response header is set to /.

The only difference in the content for the two above scenarios is having an apostrophe and/or semicolon.

Comment: Turns out this was happening due to the web application firewall that the site is behind.